# Weird error in Backbone: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token B

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token Bn.get_api_token 
@ ain.js:14s.sync 
@ services.js:10i.Model.extend.sync 
@ UserHeaderModel.js:13n.extend.fetch 
@ backbone.js:599i.View.extend.initialize 
@ UserHeaderView.js:13e.View 
@ backbone.js:1192i 
@ backbone.js:1852e.exports.i.View.extend.initialize
@ HeaderView.js:16e.View 
@ backbone.js:1192i 
@ backbone.js:1852i.Router.extend.initialize 
@ router.js:14e.Router 
@ backbone.js:1440i 
@ backbone.js:1852a.init 
@ app.js:10o.1../router 
@ app.js:39r 
@ _prelude.js:1t 
@ _prelude.js:1(anonymous function) 
@ _prelude.js:1
```

Everything was working fine till sometime back however now i get this weird error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token B
```

My services.js code:

```
    var $ = jQuery = require('jquery'),
    Handlebars = require('handlebars'),
    Backbone = require('backbone'),
    mainJs = require('./main');

var services = {

    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        var self = this;
        var api_token = mainJs.get_api_token();
        var access_token;
        if (api_token == null) {
            access_token = api_token;

        } else {
            access_token = api_token.access_token;
        }

        options || (options = {});

        var beforeSend = options.beforeSend;
        options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token)
            if (beforeSend) return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
        };

        switch (method) {
            case "read":
                options.url = options.readUrl;
                break;
            case "delete":
                options.url = options.deleteUrl;
                break;
            case "update":
                options.url = options.updateUrl;
                options.contentType = 'application/json';
                break;
            case "create":
                options.url = options.createUrl;
                options.contentType = 'application/json';
                break;
        }

        options.error = function (xhr, statusTxt, thrown) {
            switch (xhr.status) {
                case 401:
                    console.log("Unauthorized error");
                    break;
                default:
                    var messageText = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);;
                    console.log("Status code: " + xhr.status + " Error: " + messageText.message);
            }
        }

        if (options.url)
            return Backbone.sync.call(model, method, model, options);

    }

}


module.exports = services;
```

main.js

```
    var mainJs = {
    get_api_token: function () {
        var apiat = null;
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
            var kv = cookies[i].split("=");
            if (kv[0].trim() === "API") {
                apiat = kv[1].trim();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (apiat) {
            return JSON.parse(apiat);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

module.exports = mainJs;
```

Please help

Comment: Can you share some of your code? As a first guess I would say it's a parsing problem. `ain.js` might try to load some resource that has unexpected content.

Comment: i am using browserify and running gulp.

Comment: What is the url of your `UserHeaderModel`. Try it, and see if the output is as expected. We can't help you more than that if you're not willing to share more of your code. Sorry.

Comment: @YoannM posted my code...

Comment: Thanks. What is `mainJs.get_api_token()` doing? It looks like the problem is in here as stated by your stack trace.

Comment: added my main.js code

Comment: Your `JSON.parse(apiat)` might be parsing something not JSON. Can you print `apiat` you'll find your problem.

Comment: yes i found the problem i was getting a non json request thanks :)

Comment: I've added this as an answer for later reference.

Comment: Hi @Vini, why you deleted your recent question? Did you got the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSON.parse(apiat)` might be parsing something not JSON.

If you print `apiat` you'll find your problem.

A good practice is to **always** wrap `JSON.parse` in a `try {} catch ()` clause :

```
try {
    JSON.parse(data);
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Error parsing JSON', e);
}
```